# Can I use Datel Data Max as a means to retrieve any saved progress in PS2 memory card using GNU/Linux and PSX2?

Tags: linux, ps2

In my computer I want to have a way to be able to play ps2 games via the PSX2 emulator and store my game's progress in a ps2 memory card so I can continue in mt ps2.

In ebay I found the [Datel Data Max](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Datel-Data-Max-Playstation-2-Memory-Card-Reader-USB-zu-Playstaion-3-oder-PC/313321912979?hash=item48f370fa93:g:FssAAOSwPDtfw8HF) as means of using usb to save and retrieve the data from memory card reader. But my computers Uses GNU/Linux and I do not plan to chane the OS.

So I wonder if you have ever used it with GNU/Linux as means of saving or retrieving data from playstation2 memory card.